# Django: Count related model where an annotation on the related has a specific value and store count in an annotation (or simply: count subquery)

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two models `Pick` and `GamePick`. `GamePick` has a `ForeignKey` relation to `Pick`, which is accessible on `Pick.game_picks`.

I have setup `GamePick` with a custom queryset and manger so that when ever I retrieve a `GamePick` with the manager `objects` is is annotated with a field `is_correct` based on the values of other fields.

Now what I want to be able to do is count the how many correct `GamePicks` are pointing to a specific `Pick`.

One simple way is doing this with a method in Python:

```py
class Pick(models.Model):

    ...

    def count_correct(self):
        return self.game_picks.filter(is_correct=True).count()
```

So far so good.

But now, I would like to annotate each `Pick` with that count, say as `correct_count`. This is so I can order the `Pick` with something like `Pick.objects.all().order_by("correct_count")`.

Now how would I do this?

This is where I am:

```py
correct_game_picks = GamePick.objects.filter(
    pick=models.OuterRef("pk"),
    is_correct=True
)

picks = Pick.objects.annotate(
    correct_count=models.Count(correct_game_picks.values("pk"))
)
```

This is what `pick.query` gives me:

```
SELECT 
    "picks_pick"."id", 
    "picks_pick"."picker", 
    "picks_pick"."pot_id", 
    COUNT((
        SELECT U0."id" FROM "picks_gamepick" U0 
        INNER JOIN "games_game" U1 ON (U0."game_id" = U1."id") 
        WHERE ((U0."picked_team_id" = U1."winning_team_id") AND U0."pick_id" = "picks_pick"."id")
    )) AS "correct_count" 
FROM "picks_pick" 
GROUP BY "picks_pick"."id", "picks_pick"."picker", "picks_pick"."pot_id"
```

I am not good at SQL, but it seems like it should be correct.

In my test, it returns 1 when it should 2 for two correct `GamePick` belonging to a `Pick`.

Does anybody have any pointers?

---

Btw, if I remove the `.values("pk")` I get this error:

```
E       django.db.utils.OperationalError: sub-select returns 5 columns - expected 1
```

I am not sure why it matters how many column I have when I want to count rows.

---

As feedback suggests that this is hard to debug without knowing the models, here they are:

```py
class Pot(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)


class Game(models.Model):
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(
        Team,
        related_name="+",
    )
    winning_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="+",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )


class Pick(models.Model):
    picker = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Name of the person picking")

    # This is the method is would like to replace with an annotation
    def count_correct_method(self):
        return self.game_picks.filter(is_correct=True).count()


class GamePickQueryset(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_is_correct(self):
        return self.annotate(
            is_correct=models.ExpressionWrapper(
                models.Q(picked_team=models.F("game__winning_team")),
                output_field=models.BooleanField(),
            )
        )


class GamePickManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = GamePickQueryset(self.model, using=self._db)
        queryset = queryset.annotate_is_correct()
        return queryset


GamePickMangerFromQueryset = GamePickManager.from_queryset(GamePickQueryset)


class GamePick(models.Model):
    pick = models.ForeignKey(
        Pick, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="game_picks", null=True, blank=True
    )
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name="game_picks")
    picked_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+", null=True, blank=False
    )

    objects = GamePickMangerFromQueryset()
```

With these models, I am running this as a test in which I am trying to get the annotation working

```py
team_1 = Team(name="Test Team 1")
team_1.save()
team_2 = Team(name="Test Team 2")
team_2.save()
team_3 = Team(name="Test Team 3")
team_3.save()
team_4 = Team(name="Test Team 4")
team_4.save()
team_5 = Team(name="Test Team 5")
team_5.save()
team_6 = Team(name="Test Team 6")
team_6.save()
assert Team.objects.count() == 6

pot = Pot(name="Test Pot")
pot.save()
assert Pot.objects.count() == 1
assert Pot.objects.first() == pot

game_1 = Game(pot=pot)
game_1.save()
game_1.teams.add(team_1, team_2)
game_1.winning_team = team_1
game_1.save()
game_2 = Game(pot=pot)
game_2.save()
game_2.teams.add(team_3, team_4)
game_2.winning_team = team_3
game_2.save()
game_3 = Game(pot=pot)
game_3.save()
game_3.teams.add(team_5, team_6)
game_3.winning_team = team_5
game_3.save()
assert Game.objects.count() == 3
assert pot.games.count() == 3
assert pot.games.all()[0].winning_team == team_1
assert pot.games.all()[1].winning_team == team_3
assert pot.games.all()[2].winning_team == team_5

pick = Pick(picker="Tester", pot=pot)
pick.save()
assert Pick.objects.count() == 1

game_pick_1 = GamePick(pick=pick, game=game_1, picked_team=team_1)
game_pick_1.save()
game_pick_2 = GamePick(pick=pick, game=game_2, picked_team=team_3)
game_pick_2.save()
game_pick_3 = GamePick(pick=pick, game=game_3, picked_team=team_6)
game_pick_3.save()

assert GamePick.objects.count() == 3
assert pick.game_picks.count() == 3
assert pick.game_picks.all()[0].is_correct == True
assert pick.game_picks.all()[1].is_correct == True
assert pick.game_picks.all()[2].is_correct == False
assert pick.count_correct() == 2

from django.db import models

correct_game_picks = GamePick.objects.filter(
    pick=models.OuterRef("pk"),
    is_correct=True,
)

pick = Pick.objects.all().annotate(
    correct_count=models.Count(
        # models.Q(game_picks__in=correct_game_picks)
        models.Q(game_picks__picked_team=models.F("game_picks__game__winning_team"))
    )
)[0]

assert pick.correct_count == 2
```

In this test I get `3 == 2`. For some reason, it is counting all the `game_picks` not only the ones that fulfill the expression.

Really don't know what to do with that anymore...

I just realized (thanks to @BradMeinsberger), since I am doing that `__in` expression, I should not really need the `OuterRef`.

So the annotation can be just this:

```py
correct_game_picks = GamePick.objects.filter(
    is_correct=True,
)

pick = Pick.objects.all().annotate(
    correct_count=models.Count(
        models.Q(game_picks__in=correct_game_picks)
    )
)[0]
```

But now the kicker: without the `OuterRef` I can evaluate the correct game picks separately:

```py
assert correct_game_picks.count() == 2
assert pick.correct_count == 2
```

The first assert passes but the second does not with `3 == 2` 
How can there be more than 2 in a list of 2?

Is there some kind of duplicate happening?

Now I can through a `distinct=True` into the `Count` and it passes

Let's test another combination e.g. only 1 correct game pick:

```py
game_pick_1 = GamePick(pick=pick, game=game_1, picked_team=team_1)
game_pick_1.save()
game_pick_2 = GamePick(pick=pick, game=game_2, picked_team=team_4)
game_pick_2.save()
game_pick_3 = GamePick(pick=pick, game=game_3, picked_team=team_6)
game_pick_3.save()

assert GamePick.objects.count() == 3
assert pick.game_picks.count() == 3
assert pick.game_picks.all()[0].is_correct == True
assert pick.game_picks.all()[1].is_correct == False
assert pick.game_picks.all()[2].is_correct == False
assert pick.count_correct() == 1

from django.db import models

correct_game_picks = GamePick.objects.filter(
    is_correct=True,
)

pick = Pick.objects.all().annotate(
    correct_count=models.Count(
        models.Q(game_picks__in=correct_game_picks),
        distinct=True
    )
)[0]

assert correct_game_picks.count() == 1
assert pick.correct_count == 1
```

`2 == 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got it!

I guess I was making it more complicated than it needed to be.

```py
correct_game_picks = GamePick.objects.filter(
    pick=models.OuterRef("pk"),
    is_correct=True
)

picks = Pick.objects.annotate(
    correct_count=models.Count(
        models.Q(game_picks__in=correct_game_picks)
    )
)
```

and the resulting SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    "picks_pick"."id", 
    "picks_pick"."picker", 
    "picks_pick"."pot_id", 
    COUNT(
        "picks_gamepick"."id" IN (
            SELECT U0."id" FROM "picks_gamepick" U0 
            INNER JOIN "games_game" U1 ON (U0."game_id" = U1."id") 
            WHERE ((U0."picked_team_id" = U1."winning_team_id") AND U0."pick_id" = "picks_pick"."id"))
    ) AS "correct_count" 
FROM "picks_pick" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "picks_gamepick" ON ("picks_pick"."id" = "picks_gamepick"."pick_id") 
GROUP BY "picks_pick"."id", "picks_pick"."picker", "picks_pick"."pot_id"
```

This seemingly unrelated blog post I came a across when searching for "Django subquery count" pointed me in the right direction:
https://mattrobenolt.com/the-django-orm-and-subqueries/

---

**Nope.** The above does not work. For some reason it only counts the number of game picks... ‍♂️

---

Guess a proper look into the docs is always helpful:

```py
correct_game_picks = GamePick.objects.filter(
    is_correct=True,
)

picks = Pick.objects.all().annotate(
    correct_count=models.Count(
        "game_picks",  # The field to count needs to be mentioned specifically
        filter=models.Q(game_picks__in=correct_game_picks),  # ... and you can define a filter to limit the number of rows in the aggregate
        distinct=True. # Prevent duplicates! Important for counting rows
    )
)
```

The aggregate filter is what is was looking for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter

This is the generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    "picks_pick"."id", 
    "picks_pick"."picker", 
    "picks_pick"."pot_id", 
    COUNT(
        DISTINCT "picks_gamepick"."id"
    ) FILTER (
        WHERE "picks_gamepick"."id" IN (
            SELECT U0."id" FROM "picks_gamepick" U0 
            INNER JOIN "games_game" U1 ON (U0."game_id" = U1."id") 
            WHERE (U0."picked_team_id" = U1."winning_team_id")
        )
    ) 
    AS "correct_count" 
FROM "picks_pick" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "picks_gamepick" ON ("picks_pick"."id" = "picks_gamepick"."pick_id") 
GROUP BY "picks_pick"."id", "picks_pick"."picker", "picks_pick"."pot_id"
```

Comment: In this version you are doing a join to picks_gamepick in the outerquery. In this case you don't need the subquery at all. Just do a `Count('gamepick')` for the annotation and a `.filter(is_correct=True)` in the outer query.

Comment: Sorry @BradMartsberger, I don't quite understand what that would look like.
`picks = Pick.objects.annotate(correct_count=models.Count("game_picks").filter(is_correct=True))` fails with `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.

Comment: Since you've explained that `is_correct` isn't a column, it wouldn't work like that. You could annotate is_correct and then filter by it. Maybe `.filter(picks__picked_team_id=F('picks__game__winning_team_id'))`, not certain without being able to test it.

Comment: I just setup more tests and it appears my solution is not working. This just counts all the game picks ‍♂️

Comment: @BradMartsberger I added the model definitions btw.

Answer (score 1):

In the SQL you generate the subquery inside the COUNT aggregate is joining to a games_game table that isn't anywhere else in your question. It looks like it's doing this to figure out if the pick is correct where elsewhere in your question you have a column on GamePick called is_correct that is used for this.

Here is how you would do it assuming you have the is_correct column and ignoring the games_game table

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, Count

subquery = GamePick.objects.filter(
    pick=OuterRef('id'),
    is_correct=True
).values(
    'pick_id'  # Necessary to get the proper group by
).annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).values(
    'id'  # Necessary to select only one column
)

picks = Pick.objects.annotate(correct_count=Subquery(subquery))
```

You can get the same thing using the [django-sql-utils](https://pypi.org/project/django-sql-utils/) package. `pip install django-sql-utils` and then

```
from sql_util.utils import SubqueryCount
from django.db.models import Q

subquery = SubqueryCount('game_pick', filter=Q(is_correct=True))
picks=Pick.objects.annotate(correct_count=subquery)
```

If you need to determine if the pick is correct using the games_game table, I think you would replace `is_correct=True` (in both examples above) with

```
game__winning_team_id=F('picked_team_id')
```

I'm not 100% certain since I can't see those models/columns.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach @Brad Martensberger. There actually is no `is_correct` column. That is an annotation I generate on the the `GamePick` through a custom model manager. That is actually what makes the subquery necessary (instead of just being able to use `game_picks__is_correct`).

Comment: Btw, I just posted another answer a minute or so before yours came in. I had just realised that I am making it more complex than necessary. Looks like Django is now capable of counting on subqueries natively.

Comment: I just tried your solution and it gives me `1 == 2`. So it returns only a count of 1 when it should be 2 (out of 3 total).